Why was my Windows Server 2012 R2 and TLS question closed as off-topic?
I posted a question about Windows Server 2012 R2 and how Windows Server chooses the protocol for the client hello packet
However, the question was closed soon after due to being off-topic. I have looked at the FAQ about the type of questions that can be asked and am still unclear as to how my question is "off-topic".
My question was about managing an IT system in a business environment and it was not about something used in a home-setting, licensing or product recommendations.
Here are several questions that are similar that have not been closed.

TLS communication: client did not receive "server key exchange" message but server got the ack
Disabling TLS 1.0 prevents Client HELLO packet

Please let me know what was off-topic so I can fix my question for the future.

managing an IT system in a business environment businesses that follow normal and reasonable practices don't use Windows Server 2012.

Windows Server 2012 is off topic due to it is end of life.
It's the same for Windows Server 2008 or 2003.
